# Change color turtle when it creates a new object

Tags: netlogo

When an agent of breed A is selected, it creates a new object. I would need to add this object to both its list (`agenda`) and neighbours'. If I've made no mistakes in the code below, I'd ask you how to change color to the agent and not to the object.

Thanks

```
breed[objects object]
objects-own[att_1]

breed [A aa]
A-own[
  my-object
  agenda
]

to setup
  create-A 10
  ask A[
    set agenda []
  ]
end

to go
[
  ask one-of A[create-obj]
]
end

to create-object
   create-object 1[
      if breed = A
        [set color red] ; I want to assign this colour to A, not to the object      
        hide-turtle
        set att_1 random-float 1
        let this-object myself
        if (condition 1)
              [ let customers (turtle-set self in-link-neighbors with [breed = A])
                ask customers
                [
                  set agenda fput this-object agenda
                ]
              ]      
         ]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `if breed = A [set color red]` with `if breed = A [ask myself [set color red]]`. Does that work?

The keyword `myself` refers to the one doing the asking rather than the turtle implementing the commands it has been asked to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not used the keyword `myself` so often. Can I ask you if it is correct to use let this-object myself and `set agenda fput this-object` to let an agent `A` to put the object created into its agenda (A's agenda)?

Comment: I don't understand the question sorry. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I tried but I received an error message because of `create-object` (I had to ask a new question as the issue was not related to this one). So I cannot check if it works or not

Comment: Using `if breed = A [ask myself [set color red]]` inside `create-object` will never do anything, since the breed of the turtle will always be `object`, never `A`. The answer should have just been `ask myself [ set color red ]`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you were trying to achieve, I think the solution can be as simple as:

```
to go
  ask one-of A [
    set color red
    create-obj
  ]
end
```

In general, you almost never need to use the `if breed = ...` pattern. If you find yourself doing that, you're most likely approaching the problem in the wrong way, and there is usually to achieve what you want. (You're always welcome to ask about it here, of course.)